# What is the difference between a module in a monolithic kernel and a server in a microkernel?

Tags: operating-systems, os-kernel

I´m not exactly sure what kind of impact these two things have on kernel design. Are servers more flexible because of running in user space, for instance, and does adding a module require a new build of a kernel?

Comment: Welcome! I am unsure as to the scope of your question. Are you sure it is a CS question, that is refers to operating system (theory) in general? Or would you rather discuss implementation details of specific OSs?

Comment: It might be more suitable for [superuser.com](http://superuser.com).

Comment: @DaveClarke I'm pretty sure that [su] would close this question as too theoretical, they're rather focused on “how do I do X”-type questions. [unix.se] is more open to “how does this work under the hood”, but even there I think the question would be considered borderline. I think this question is ok here as a general question on OS design.

Comment: @Raphael I'm just looking into OS theory, not a specific OS. I'd say it falls within the field of computer science, since it's a general question Gilles stated.

Comment: I'm certainly happy for it to stay here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, a `module` runs at the same memory space than the kernel and a `server` runs in a different one.

Although a `module` can surely be added/removed on-the-fly (linux kernel does that), any misbehavior caused by it may affect the entire system, whether in the micro-kernel architecture, only the `server` gets compromised.

Comment: Rather than "memory space", one should probably say "protection domain". In addition, the protection is not absolute; a server's misbehavior can become a denial of service attack or exploit bugs in other code that would not manifest under normal provision of the server's functionality.